# Lenovo - Monitor - 6.13.3.0 driver

Tags: windows-10, drivers, thinkpad

Since early April my Thinkpad x380 yoga behaves very unstable with Windows 10.

I think that it is not a hardware problem, since when I boot with Ubuntu (Dualboot) everything works perfect.

So I checked recent updates and I think Lenovo - Monitor - 6.13.3.0 driver could be the reason for my problems, because it was installed approximately when the problems have started to appear?

Or Lenovo Vantage shows me that the installation Intel HD Graphics Driver is also not that long time ago:

[image] 
[image]

I experience the following problems:

Chrome cannot open website claiiming htat there is not enough memory (Windows tells me that there are approcximately 8GB of 16GB RAM free)
Firefox crashes.
All my monitors go black for a few seconds (sometimes some beep signals come out of my laptop during this black screen period), then my external monitors stay black but my internal monitor is reactivated and shows me that the display dirver could not be started and that therefore the basic display driver is used instead:
[image]
Zoom reports application cannot be executed.
Windows Defender and Avira Antivirus are suddenly deactivated.
Sometimes my system gets into a mode where my attemts to close windows result in blurry (doubled) versions of the windows instead of closing them.
And some other strange behavior in connection with graphics/display/monitor.
This strange behavior started shortly after I installed Anaconda, updated Firefox, zoom and chrome, maybeone of those programs did something wrong.
All these bugs seem to be highly correlated (if the browser crashes typically a few seconds minutes later the displays go black and so on)
Everytime I reboot the problems disappear but after a few minutes or hours they appear again :(

Where do you think is the problem? How can I fix it? Do you think ti would make sence to downgrade the Lenovo Monitor dirver to an older version or just reinstall it (how?) or do you think the intel graphics driver is the troublemaker?

@[John](https://superuser.com/users/1079976/john):
[image]

Comment: Open Device Manager.  First look in Display, right click on the Video driver and select update.  Second look in Monitor, right click on driver and select update. My Monitor driver is 6.14.1 (different Lenovo laptop).  Then consider updating BIOS and Chipset drivers.

Comment: Regarding Chrome and Firefox, disabling hardware acceleration can solve your instability issues.

Comment: @John Using you advice, I updated the monitor driver to 6.14.4.0 via the device manager. There was no update avaialble for the GPU. (I did not find "Display" or a German equivalent.)

Comment: You may wish to update BIOS if updating the monitor driver did not help

Comment: At the moement everything works fine, after I updated Lenovo monitor driver. I hope it stays like that :)

Comment: I just updated my own driver to .4 and it works fine. If I post my answer, will you acknowledge it?

Comment: Unfortunately the display driver error is back again :(

Comment: Try updating BIOS on this device

Comment: pcsupport.lenovo.com tells me that the latest BIOS-version is 1.33 from January. Lenovo Vantage tells me that I have already R0SET49W 1.33, so there is no need to update the BIOS. I don't want to use any experimental driver for the BIOS. If I mess up my BIOS I would also destroy the possibility to boot into Ubunu in the worst case, which would be extremely bad for me. I found some Thunderbolt updates on the lenovo page which Vantage hasn't show to me. Do you think I should try installing them?

Comment: You wrote "Do you think I should try installing them? "  I cannot say with certainty.  My own Monitor driver remains at 6.14.4 2 months later.

Comment: Today I updated my monitor drirver via the windows device manager and now I got 6.14.5.0 from May 27. Lenovo Vantage has not updated it for a very long time and on pcsupport.lenovo.com Lenovo tells me that ThinkPad Monitor INF File Version 6.10.0.0 from May 28 would be a recommended update. Do you understand that version numbering? Why do these different sources of updtes beahve so differently?

Comment: Lenovo has made numerous revisions to this driver. I see an old 6.06 driver from 2018 in my file. I have been updating my machine regularly and am still at 6.14.4. (A) I am not sure about their recommendations.  (B) is your machine still unstable?

Comment: I am not sure if it is still unstable. I only used Ubuntu the last months. Now, I am using windows for a couple of hours without crash. I hope it stay that way and it won't crash tomorrow during my power point presentation

Comment: If it has stabilized you may wish to mark my response helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Device Manager. First look in Display, right click on the Video driver and select update. Second look in Monitor, right click on driver and select update.

Also update the BIOS on your machine

My Monitor driver is 6.14.1 (different Lenovo laptop), which I then updated to 6.14.4 and both worked properly.

Comment: I don't know what exactly solved the problem , but now my system seems to be stable again. I updated the monitor dirver as you suggested, then I didn't use my windows 10 for a couple of months and afterwards I installed all the updates recommend by Lenovo Vantage and Windows Updates (and Firefox, zoom,...). Probably a combination of some of these updates solved my problem.

Comment: Thank you for the update.

Comment: had a similar problem after windows update automatically updated my drivers to 6.14.10 (i'm on a Gen 6 Carbon x1) - manually rolling back did not work. Had to totally uninstall the drivers using https://www.guru3d.com/files-details/display-driver-uninstaller-download.html then reinstall an older version (6.10.0) from the lenovo drivers site, seems to be fine now. What a massive hassle, made sure to disable windows update of hardware drivers afterwards...never update anything.